# Return the most used words in a spreadsheet - Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a VBA function which returns the most used words in a pre-defined Excel spreadsheet of over 82000 rows.

I also understand how basic my knowledge is.

```vb
Public Sub MostCommon()
Dim MyRange As Range, MyDict As Object, MyData
Dim i As Long, j As Long, wk, x

    Set MyRange = Range("G2:G81200")
    
    Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    MyData = MyRange.Value
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(MyData)
        wk = Split(MyData(i, 1))
        For j = 0 To UBound(wk)
            MyDict.Item(wk(j)) = MyDict.Item(wk(j)) + 1
        Next j
    Next i
    
    i = 1
    For Each x In MyDict
        Cells(i, "M") = x
        Cells(i, "N") = MyDict.Item(x)
        i = i + 1
    Next x
    
    With ActiveSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N:N"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
        .SetRange Range("M:N")
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? (It should be highlighted yellow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a test: Code works if all data is okay.

However, I got the error when a cell contained a formula that resulted in an error. An error is not a string like `#Value`, `#N/A` or `#DIV/0`, an error is an own data type in Excel (and in VBA) and cannot be "splitted", therefore the `Split` raises a Type Mismatch.

You can check for an cell-value error to avoid the runtime error:

```
    If Not IsError(MyData(i, 1)) Then
        wk = Split(MyData(i, 1))

        For j = 0 To UBound(wk)
            MyDict.Item(wk(j)) = MyDict.Item(wk(j)) + 1
        Next j
    End If
```

If you still get the same runtime error, check the value of `MyData(i, 1)` with the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

### Most Used Words in Column

- FunThomas has probably answered your question. This is just an idea of how to improve. The least efficient part of your code is writing to the range. You can vastly improve efficiency by using the `GetDictionary` function.
- The following solution will return two columns, the first containing each unique word from cells of a column, and the second containing the count (number of occurrences) of each word.

```vb
Option Explicit

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      ... most common ...
' Calls:        'RefColumn','GetRange','DictArrayCountNoErrors','GetDictionary'.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub MostCommon()
    
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "G2"
    Const dfCellAddress As String = "M1"
    Const dcCount As Long = 2 ' keys and items (count)
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' be more specific
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(sfCellAddress)
    Dim scrg As Range: Set scrg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    If scrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = GetRange(scrg)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare ' A=a

    Dim wk() As String
    Dim sKey As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 1 To UBound(sData)
        sKey = sData(r, 1)
        If Not IsError(sKey) Then
            wk = Split(CStr(sKey))
            DictArrayCountNoErrors dict, wk
        End If
    Next r
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dict.Count
    If drCount = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Erase sData
    
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = GetDictionary(dict)
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = ws.Range(dfCellAddress)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(drCount, dcCount)
    drg.Value = dData
    Erase dData
    
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Set dcrg = drg.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - drCount + 1).Offset(drCount)
    dcrg.ClearContents
    
    drg.Sort Key1:=drg.Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    ' To additionally sort first column ascending:
    'drg.Sort Key1:=drg.Columns(2), Order1:=xlDescending, _
        Key2:=drg.Columns(1), Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
    
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Adds the values of an array to the keys of an existing
'               dictionary and updates the count in the dictionary's items.
' Remarks:      It is assumed that there are no error values, while blanks
'               are excluded.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Sub DictArrayCountNoErrors( _
        ByRef dict As Object, _
        ByVal Arr As Variant)
    Dim Key As Variant, n As Long
    For n = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Key = Arr(n)
        If Len(CStr(Key)) > 0 Then
            dict(Key) = dict(Key) + 1
        End If
    Next n
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values from a dictionary in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      F, F, F - returns the keys and items in two columns.
'               F, F, T - returns the items and keys in two columns.
'               F, T, F - returns the keys in a column.
'               F, T, T - returns the items in a column.
'               T, F, F - returns the keys and items in two rows.
'               T, F, T - returns the items and keys in two rows.
'               T, T, F - returns the keys in a row.
'               T, T, T - returns the items in a row.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetDictionary( _
    Dictionary As Object, _
    Optional ByVal Horizontal As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal FirstOnly As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal Flip As Boolean = False) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetDictionary"
    On Error GoTo ClearError

    If Not Dictionary Is Nothing Then
        Dim NoE As Long
        NoE = Dictionary.Count
        If NoE > 0 Then
            Dim Data As Variant
            Dim Key As Variant
            Dim i As Long
            If Not Horizontal Then
                If Not FirstOnly Then
                    ReDim Data(1 To NoE, 1 To 2)
                    If Not Flip Then
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(i, 1) = Key
                            Data(i, 2) = Dictionary(Key)
                        Next Key
                    Else
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(i, 1) = Dictionary(Key)
                            Data(i, 2) = Key
                        Next Key
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Data(1 To NoE, 1 To 1)
                    If Not Flip Then
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(i, 1) = Key
                        Next Key
                    Else
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(i, 1) = Dictionary(Key)
                        Next Key
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If Not FirstOnly Then
                    ReDim Data(1 To 2, 1 To NoE)
                    If Not Flip Then
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(1, i) = Key
                            Data(2, i) = Dictionary(Key)
                        Next Key
                    Else
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(1, i) = Dictionary(Key)
                            Data(2, i) = Key
                        Next Key
                    End If
                Else
                    ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To NoE)
                    If Not Flip Then
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(1, i) = Key
                        Next Key
                    Else
                        For Each Key In Dictionary.Keys
                            i = i + 1
                            Data(1, i) = Dictionary(Key)
                        Next Key
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            GetDictionary = Data
        Else
            Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
              & "Dictionary is empty."
        End If
    Else
        Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': " _
          & "Dictionary is not defined ('Nothing')."
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "': Unexpected Error!" & vbLf _
              & "    " & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf _
              & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```